# Bash - compare file path to list of forbidden paths

Tags: bash-scripting

I was using:

```
for file in $(find "$1" -maxdepth 10000 -xdev -ignore_readdir_race); do
```

to load files from the internal drives as a means of warming up the ZFS ARC. $1 is the starting directory, an argument passed when starting the code.

I was informed on SU that doing it this way is erroneous, so I now use:

```
while read -r file; do
```

and rely upon code further down to avoid loading files from external drives (it just counts and classifies those files). The code classifies the files into Directories | Cached Files (ie: files which have been used to warm up the ZFS ARC) | Symbolic Links | Block Devices | Character Devices | Pipes | Sockets | Zero Length Files | Skipped Files | Stale Files (files that existed on the last run of locate, but no longer do).

It is the code to classify files as Skipped Files that I'm having trouble with.

I've attempted to use either of:

```
if [[ "$file" == *"$OP0"* ]]
if [[ "$file" =~ *"$OP0"* ]]
```

... `$file` is the file path of the file being processed, and $OP0 is an omitted path. One such omitted path is OP1="/media/$USER", where all the external drives are.

I've attempted to use:

```
case $file in (*$OP0*)
  SkipCnt++
esac
```

I've attempted to use:

```
if [[ contains "$file" "$OP0" ]]
```

... where 'contains' is a function.

I've attempted to use:

```
if [[ $file =~ ^($OP0)$ ]]
```

I've attempted to use:

```
if [[ $file -ef $OP0 ]]
```

The commands work in Terminal... but when put into a script (exactly the same code as ran successfully in Terminal), they do not. Hence the if elif fi code I've got that merely counts files on external drives, and loads files on the internal drives to populate the ZFS ARC (the internal drives only hold the OS and associated files, all other files are stored on external drives), doesn't work, so the cache gets polluted with a bunch of archived stuff.

Here is the code that loads the files (actually, copies them to /dev/null):

```
# You can use any one of these three, listed fastest to slowest
tar -cS --no-recursion --warning=none "$file" &>/dev/null
# cp --preserve=all --reflink=never "$file" /dev/null
# cat "$file" 1>/dev/null
```

So... which command should I be using, and how do I get it working in a script run from sudo?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

For instance, this code blurb:

```
OP0=/media/$USER/; OP1=/mnt; OP2=; OP3=; file=/boot/efi/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_camellia.mod; if [[ "$file" =~ ^( "$OP0" || "$OP1" )$ ]] ; then echo $OP0; echo $OP1; echo $file ; fi
```

... works in an interactive terminal. I took that file name and path from the screen printout of $file.

It reflects the settings in the script. It correctly shows that there is no match between $file and $OP0 or $OP1... but in the script it fails to show that, so all files that would be tallied as "Skipped" (ie: files on external drives) are instead tallied as the other categories, and since most of them are regular files, they get copied to /dev/null and thus loaded into ZFS ARC.

The correlating code in the script would be:

```
if [[ "$file" =~ ^( "$OP0" || "$OP1" )$ ]] ; then (( SkipCnt++ ))
```

...that's it, that's all the code does for that file type, just iterates a counter (except it doesn't work in a script)... below that are the elif's for the other categorizations.

The one for the files that aren't zero-length, exist in the locate database, aren't directories, aren't block devices, aren't character devices, aren't pipes, aren't symbolic links, aren't sockets... those files get copied to /dev/null and thus loaded into ZFS ARC.

Comment: "The commands work (…) but when put into a script (…), they do not." – A command may "not work" in many different ways. What is the error message (if any)? Or what is the wrong result? and what is the expected result? Can you provide [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367021/10765659)?

Comment: It doesn't ever match the path of the file being operated upon with the omitted path, so the code loads the files on external drives. The code runs without errors, it just never matches when it's in a script. Works fine in an interactive terminal, though... I've been beating my head against this particular brick wall for many hours now.

Comment: For instance, this runs fine in an interactive terminal: IFS=""; OP0=/media/$USER/; OP1=/mnt; OP2=; OP3=; file=/boot/efi/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_camellia.mod; if  [[ $file == *"$OP0"* ]] ; then echo $OP0; echo $OP1; echo $file ; fi   .... but copy the relevant bits to a script, and no joy.

Comment: You should add information to the question ([edit] the question) with proper formatting instead of placing it in comments.

Comment: Variable scoping, maybe? Where you have the current problematic line, have you tried to add `echo $OP0 $OP1 $SkipCnt` or similar, to see what values the script is working with? I'm with @KamilMaciorowski, the command should not behave in different ways in interactive terminal vs shell script.

Comment: Yes, I've done that... I figured it out... all of the code snippets were glitching on empty strings! I'd set up several Omitted Paths variables, $OP0 to $OP9. Only $OP0 and $OP1 were populated, the others were ="". The code didn't like that, it was false-positiving on that. To fix it, I set $OP2 through 9 = /dev/null. Unconventional, but the code is working.